# Configuring CORS using CLI in IBM Cloud Object Storage Bucket

Tags: cors, ibm-cloud, config, bucket, cloud-object-storage

```
p@p:/home$ ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put --bucket test --cors-configuration "./corsconfig.json"
FAILED
The value in flag '--cors-configuration' is invalid
NAME: 
   ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put - Set the CORS configuration on a bucket

USAGE:
   ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put --bucket BUCKET_NAME [--cors-configuration STRUCTURE] [--region REGION] [--output FORMAT] [--json]

OPTIONS:
   --bucket BUCKET_NAME            The name (BUCKET_NAME) of the bucket.
   --cors-configuration STRUCTURE  A STRUCTURE using JSON syntax in a file. See IBM Cloud Documentation.
   --region REGION                 The REGION where the bucket is present. If this flag is not provided, the program will use the default option specified in config.
   --output FORMAT                 Output FORMAT can be only json or text.
   --json                          [Deprecated] Output returned in raw JSON format.
```

**I am receiving the above error when configuring cors on my bucket**

*corsconfig.json contents:*

```
{
"CORSRules": [
{
"AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
"AllowedMethods": ["GET"],
"AllowedOrigins": ["*"]
}
]
}
```

**I tried using**

- relative path
- absolute path
- with and without quotes for the above

**In the error it mentions:**

```
Set the CORS configuration on a bucket
```

**So I tried running:**

```
p@p:/home$ ibmcloud target -r jp-tok
Switched to region jp-tok


                   
API endpoint:      https://cloud.ibm.com
Region:            jp-tok
User:              <my email>
Account:           <my account>
Resource group:    No resource group targeted, use 'ibmcloud target -g RESOURCE_GROUP'
CF API endpoint:   
Org:               
Space:
```

**But there is a bucket in that region:**

[image]

What am I missing, can someone help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the IBM Cloud documentation to [set a Cloud Object Storage bucket CORS](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli#ic-set-bucket-cors), you need to use the `file://` prefix to load the JSON from a specified file.

```bash
ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put --bucket test --cors-configuration file://corsconfig.json
```

> JSON Syntax: --cors-configuration file://<filename.json> ======= The
> --cors-configuration command takes a JSON structure that describes the CORS configuration. In this example, the file:// prefix is used to
> load the JSON structure from the specified file.

Comment: Glad the answer helped. Can you mark this as answer?